# Updating sharepoint list items with batch pnp, in bad request

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, pnp

I've used this [guide](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items#update-multiple-items) to create my batch and update the items.

```
var list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Categories");
list.getListItemEntityTypeFullName().then(entityTypeFullName => {
    var batch = pnp.sp.createBatch();
    $(`.${css.SortContent} table tbody tr`).each(function (ind, con) {
        var id: any = $(con).attr("data-catid");
        var newOrder: any = parseInt($(con).find(`.cat_select :selected`).text());
        list.items.getById(id).inBatch(batch).update({
            Order: newOrder
        }, "*", entityTypeFullName).then(() => {
            console.log("test");
        });
    });
    batch.execute().then(r => {
        console.log(r);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Information: There are 3 `tr`'s inside the `body`. In my test, they give these results:

`id = 1; newOrder = 2`
`id = 2; newOrder = 1`
`id = 3; newOrder = 3`

When I run the code, this is the following result:

`console.log(test)` never runs
`console.log(r)` logs undefined
`console.log(e)` never runs

If I log `batch` just before it's executed, I'm able to see 3 items inside. So I know the items are added to the `batch`.

But the items are never updated, and all I get is.

> Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400] Bad Request

Image of the batch log:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** It looks like `"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"` is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to get the `entityTypeFullName` via REST API calls when making updates in a single list.

Similarly, you need not pass the `entityTypeFullName` parameter while making an update request because the framework will handle it for you.

Modify the code as below and check:

```
var list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Categories");

var batch = pnp.sp.createBatch();
$(`.${css.SortContent} table tbody tr`).each(function (ind, con) {
    var id: any = $(con).attr("data-catid");
    var newOrder: any = parseInt($(con).find(`.cat_select :selected`).text());
    list.items.getById(id).inBatch(batch).update({
        Order: newOrder
    }).then(d => {
        console.log("test" + d);
    });
});
batch.execute().then(r => {
    console.log(r);
    console.log("batch update successful");
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

If you are using it inside SPFx context, make sure to initialize the PnP context as below in your webpart's `.ts` file before the `Render` method:

```
/**
* Initialize the web part.
*/
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

 return super.onInit().then(_ => {
   pnp.setup({
     spfxContext: this.context
   });
 });
}
```

FYI - i just tried the below code with hardcoded ID values and it works successfully.

```
var list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Custom List');

var batch = pnp.sp.web.createBatch();

list.items.getById(1).inBatch(batch).update({
    Title: "Updated from batch 1"
}).then(d => console.log(d));

list.items.getById(2).inBatch(batch).update({
    Title: "Updated from batch 2"
}).then(d => console.log(d));

list.items.getById(3).inBatch(batch).update({
    Title: "Updated from batch 3"
}).then(d => console.log(d));

batch.execute().then(d => console.log("Batch update success"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your code and sadly it didnt work for me. still the same error

Comment: Gautam, I've updated the post with a new image, It looks like `"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"` is missing, is that correct?

Comment: Did you try the 2nd code snippet ? What version of PnP JS are you using ? I used the `3.0.10` js from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sp-pnp-js/3.0.10/pnp.min.js) and tried it in browser console. It works

Comment: I've used npm  to install sp-pnp-js, and i've made sure it's using the latest update-

Comment: Are you using it inside spfx webpart ? Also, can you try with hardcoded values of ID and title columns? Have updated the answer to include the spfx init section.